# ClassCastException while calling SOAP API using Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am using Maven, Java 1.6, Apache CXF. I am getting some Class Cast Exception while calling the Soap API in some class of Apache CXF. Here is the stack trace.

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.net.URL cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.importCapturedData(Unknown Source)
    at com.flipkart.dynamics.api.DynamicsClientService.handleDataLoadRequest(DynamicsClientService.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.flipkart.recon.api.filter.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.URL cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.prepare(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.prepareConduitSelector(ClientImpl.java:886)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:560)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 41 more
[2014-01-28 16:07:44.572] ERROR [http-bio-8082-exec-2][ContentTypeFilter][ContentTypeFilter.java:93] Unhandled Exception. 
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.net.URL cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.importCapturedData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.flipkart.dynamics.api.DynamicsClientService.handleDataLoadRequest(DynamicsClientService.java:109) ~[DynamicsClientService.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350) ~[jersey-server-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) ~[jersey-servlet-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538) ~[jersey-servlet-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716) ~[jersey-servlet-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at com.flipkart.recon.api.filter.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:73) ~[ContentTypeFilter.class:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [na:1.6.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.URL cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:99) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.prepare(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:63) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.prepareConduitSelector(ClientImpl.java:886) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:560) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135) ~[cxf-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
try
    {
        wsdlURL =
                new URL("some http url with requiring basic authentication");
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(wsdlURL);

    OPSRequestManagement opsRequestManagement = new OPSRequestManagement(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    OPSRequestManagementPort opsRequestManagementPort = opsRequestManagement.getOPSRequestManagementPort();

    Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider) opsRequestManagementPort).getRequestContext();
    req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, wsdlURL);

    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("domain\\username"));
    headers.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("password"));
    req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);

    boolean resp;

    List<CapturedData> capturedDataList = dynamicsDao.getCapturedData(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
    FKPG fkpg = new FKPG();
    fkpg.getContent().addAll(capturedDataList);
    resp = opsRequestManagementPort.importCapturedData(fkpg);
```

Comment: Please, could you point us to the line number where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer from @sadhu pointed me in the right direction for my own problem, but it is too cryptic to my taste.

Take this snippet:

```
wsdlURL = new URL("some http url with requiring basic authentication");
```

This tells us wsdlURL is of type `java.net.URL`. Next we find this:

```
Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider) opsRequestManagementPort).getRequestContext();
req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, wsdlURL);
```

To fix the problem, change the last line to:

```
req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, wsdlURL.toExternalForm());
```

The point is that you should put a `String` object in the map, not an `URL` instance.

---

To prevent this from happening in the future, always check the Javadoc. This is what it says about the [ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider.html#ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY): (emphasis mine)

> Standard property: Target service endpoint address. The URI scheme for the endpoint address specification must correspond to the protocol/transport binding for the binding in use.
>
> **Type: java.lang.String**

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, the type of *wsdlURL* is String and it should not be. Instead

```
URL wsdlURL
```